# How to call controller function in view in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, function, zend-framework, controller

In Zend Framework, I have one controller

```
class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

    public function getResultByID( $id )
    {
        return $id;
    }

}
```

How can I call the function getResultByID in index.phtml ?

Comment: Do you really need to call the `getResultByID()` in the view? Why not call that method in the controller and pass the result to the view (which would be the more standard approach)?

Answer (score 6):

First:

```
public function indexAction()
{
  $this->view->controller = $this
}
```

In your view script:

```
<html><title><?php echo $this->controller->getResultByID($this->id); ?></title></html>
```

Comment: This is the best answer I would say. Why people haven't accepted!

Comment: zend 3 question: How can we fetch cms pages title and their links to display them in header / footer sections of entire website. Pages title and links are stored in database. Please share any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By using Action View Helper :

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action

Answer (score 0):

If the `indexAction` is executed you could call it from there:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->getResultByID( (int) $_REQUEST['id'] );
}
```

Comment: so it's impossible to call the function directly in view?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code I think this is best choice

```
public function indexAction()
    {
       $this->view->assign('id' => $this->getResultByID($this->_request->getParam('id', null)))
    }

    public function getResultByID( $id = null )
    {
        return $id;
    }
```

And in view: echo `$this->id`

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function getResultByID( $id )
  {
               return $id;
  }
```

instead of the above code u can use

```
  public function getResultByID( $id )
    {
         this->view->id=$id;
         this->render('index.phtml');
     }
```

then you can use the value of id in index.phtl as `this->id`

Answer (score 0):

In your indexAction method, return the getResultByID method in an array.

Controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return array(
       'getResult' => $this->getResultByID($id),
    );
}

public function getResultByID($id)
{
    return $id;
}
```

The question is where will you get the $id. Anyway, call the getResult string in a variable like this.

View:

```
echo $getResult;
```

And that's it.