# How to call a method of another controller in zend?

Tags: zend-framework

I have a one controller `SearchController` in Hotel module and i have a one method Search in this controller like below.

```
public function searchAction()
{

  // Code for search
  // want to call getlatlng method
}
```

now i created a one new controller `DistanceController` in same module and 
created a one `getlatlng` method in  distance controller.my getlatlng method like this.

```
 public function getlatlng()
  {
         $location = $_REQUEST['lat'].','.$_REQUEST['lng'];
         return $location;
  }
```

Now i want to call a `getlatlng` method in `searchAction` method. which returns a latitude and longitude of the current place.I pass latitude and logitude to getlatlng function using post or get.

So how can i call getlatlng method in `searchAction` method?

Comment: You may follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886291/calling-member-function-of-other-controller-in-zend-framework

Comment: Thanks @Dev , how to call getlatlng function from any view ?

Comment: Well I am not familier with zend as I work on ASP.NET MVC and PHP Laravel. Still you might get some help here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971421/how-to-call-controller-function-in-view-in-zend-framework?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Dev : Thanks a lot..

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call like this, If you are using ZF Version 1.x:

```
class SearchController extends Zend_Controller_Action 
{
    public function searchAction() {
        echo "search_action_from_SearchController";
        require_once ('DistanceController.php');
        $distanceCtrl = new DistanceController($this->_request, $this->_response);
        $distanceCtrl->xyzAction();
        die;
    }
}

class DistanceController extends Zend_Controller_Action 
{
    public function getlatlng() {
        echo "getlatlng_from_DistanceController";
        die;
    }
}
```

> Output:

```
URL: http://www.example.com/search/search
    search_action_from_SearchController
    getlatlng_from_DistanceController
```